# Why is my theoretically more efficient prime tester slower?

Tags: haskell, primes

I am experimenting with different prime testers in Haskell. This algorithm checks whether an integer *n* is prime by trying to divide it by every integer *i* from 2 to *sqrt(n)*:

```
isPrime2a n = 
    helper 2
  where
    helper i
      | (i * i) > n = True
      | mod n i == 0 = False
      | otherwise = helper (i+1)
```

I believe this implementation to test only prime divisors:

```
primes3a = 2 : 3 : filter isPrime3a [4..]
isPrime3a n = 
    not (divisibleByAny (tail primes3a))
  where
    divisibleByAny (i : rest)
      | (i * i) > n = False
      | mod n i == 0 = True
      | otherwise = divisibleByAny rest
```

This transcript shows that (contrary to my expectations) the first function is faster:

```
ghci> isPrime2a 10000000019
True
(0.14 secs, 50,455,088 bytes)

ghci> isPrime3a 10000000019
True
(1.27 secs, 475,058,704 bytes)
```

How come? Is my analysis of the algorithms incorrect, or does the overhead of building up a list outweigh the reduced number of `mod` operations?

Comment: I would recommend testing with ghc -O2 instead of ghci.

Comment: It can’t possibly be faster the first time around – it has to check whether every number `isPrime2a` considers is prime, then do extra work on top of that – but try running it a second time, now that the list is already built up. (Remember it’s evaluated lazily.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not just the memory.

Step through how this works for a reasonably small number, like 29.

`isPrime2a` has to divide 29 by 2, then by 3, then by 4, then by 5, then it stops at 6 (because 6*6 = 36, which is > 29) and reports `True`.

`isPrime3a` has to divide 29 by 2, then by 3, then by **the next element of `primes3a`**. To work out what that is `filter isPrime3a [4..]` has to divide 4 by 2 to confirm the next element isn't 4. Then `filter isPrime3a` has to divide 5 by 2, then stop at 3 to confirm 5 **is** the next element of `primes3a`.

So then `isPrime3a` can divide 29 by 5, and then we're back to needing the next element of `primes3a`, which means running `filter isPrime3a` some more. We were up to 6, so we divide 6 by 2 to find out it *isn't* the next element of `primes3a`. Then `filter isPrime3a` considers 7, which means dividing it by 2, then by 3, then stopping at 5 (4 wasn't in `primes3a`, remember) to confirm 7 *is* in `primes3a`.

Finally `isPrime3a` can stop, because 7*7 = 49, which is > 29.

That was *way* more steps! Note that `isPrime3a` only had to divide 29 by 2, 3, and 5, while `isPrime2a` had to divide 29 by 2, 3, 4, 5, and 6; `isPrime3a` got to skip over 4 and 6, saving 2 divisions. But to do that it had to divide 4 by 2, 5 by 2 and 3, 6 by 2, and 7 by 2 and 3; to save those 2 divisions we did 6 other ones! There's also some administrative overhead going on like `not` and `filter` that isn't present at all in `primes2a`, and when all you're doing is arithmetic operations stuff like that is probably significant (at least until we get to huge numbers).

However, we see different behaviour when we run each of them more than once:

```
λ isPrime2a 10000000019
True
it :: Bool
(0.07 secs, 50,474,736 bytes)
*Main
λ isPrime2a 10000000019
True
it :: Bool
(0.07 secs, 50,474,736 bytes)
*Main
λ isPrime2a 10000000019
True
it :: Bool
(0.06 secs, 50,474,736 bytes)
*Main
λ isPrime2a 10000000019
True
it :: Bool
(0.07 secs, 50,474,736 bytes)
```

Notice that it takes the same time (and memory) for repeat executions.

```
λ isPrime3a 10000000019
True
it :: Bool
(0.68 secs, 475,082,944 bytes)
*Main
λ isPrime3a 10000000019
True
it :: Bool
(0.01 secs, 4,198,032 bytes)
*Main
λ isPrime3a 10000000019
True
it :: Bool
(0.01 secs, 4,198,032 bytes)
*Main
λ isPrime3a 10000000019
True
it :: Bool
(0.02 secs, 4,198,032 bytes)
```

`isPrime3a` takes much more time and memory than `isPrime2a` on the *first* execution. Subsequent ones are much faster and allocate less; the `primes3a` list has already been built, so although it's occupying a good chunk of memory it doesn't have to be built for any following `isPrime3a` query (that doesn't need any more primes).

Also, you have a bug in your implementation.

```
λ take 20 primes3a
[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10,11,13,14,17,19,22,23,26,29,31,34,37]
it :: [Integer]
```

Because you check `not (divisibleByAny (tail primes3a))`, you never check for divisibility by the head of `primes3a`, namely 2. Thus all even numbers are reported as primes. Fixing that:

```
λ isPrime3a' 10000000019
True
it :: Bool
(0.33 secs, 230,822,560 bytes)
*Main
λ isPrime3a' 10000000019
True
it :: Bool
(0.01 secs, 2,760,760 bytes)
*Main
λ isPrime3a' 10000000019
True
it :: Bool
(0.01 secs, 2,760,760 bytes)
*Main
λ isPrime3a' 10000000019
True
it :: Bool
(0.01 secs, 2,760,760 bytes)
```

Doesn't change the conclusion really. It's still much slower than `isPrimes2` on the first execution, much faster on subsequent runs.

Long story short: **both** of these behaviours are useful. If you needed to test primality in a real program and had to choose between these two implementations, you might go for `primes2a` if you only needed to test one (or a handful) of numbers. `primes3a` looks good if you're going to test lots of numbers, and you can afford to keep a large list in memory the whole time (or you're testing numbers small enough that the list isn't large). Neither one isn't strictly better than the other, on these numbers.

Of course, as Louis Wasserman pointed out in the comments, serious performance measurement (i.e. meaningful to help you predict the performance of programs as they would be run for practical purposes) should not be made in GHCi. How to do it properly is a whole other topic, but the biggest thing you're missing is that the code is not optimised, and GHC's optimizer can make a **huge** difference to the speed and execution of code, but it is also **very** non-uniform in how much it speeds things up. It's very possible that you can have two versions of an algorithm where one is more than 10 times faster than the other when you compare an unoptimised build while the reverse is true when you compare optimised build. If you care about the performance then you'll almost always going to run it with optimisation, so that's usually the state you want to measure.